# What are these small growths on my huckleberry?

Tags: identification, shrubs, fungus

My huckleberry branches are growing through these.

Is it a fungus? Is it some kind of tumor?

[image]

[image]

these grow wild around my cabin in southcentral alaska

[image]

leaves appear to be incorporated into the thing.

[image]

here is a cross-section of the thing.

Comment: can we have a picture showing the plant and these growths please

Comment: Where did this even come from?  In the wild?  In your garden?  I've a feeling that this is a normal fungus that has babied a seed.  Great starter medium!  Way cool!  Please tell us where this came from!!

Comment: If the branches are 'growing' through these, wonder if it could be galls. Certainly need more photos to have any clue what it is.

Comment: Appears to be a [gall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gall). Can you take a cross section and photograph it?

Comment: Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: What species is your huckleberry? It's an ambiguous term that refers to a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

Just on the basis of a little websearching, I'm going to guess hackberry petiole gall:

https://bugguide.net/node/view/240449/bgimage

https://texasinsects.tamu.edu/hackberry-gall-psyllid/

https://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/pdffiles/IN/IN21400.pdf

Florida's website had it right by labeling it a "featured creature" - pretty darned interesting if you like that sort of thing, and harmless either way.  It seems to me that hackberries have more galls than even their closest competition, aspen or maybe oak.